Build Event MS Properties Blank in .Net 8 WPF Application Upgraded From .Net Framework
$(OutDir) and $(ProjectDir) MSBuild properties are empty with a .net framework 4.8 project I upgraded to .net 8 with upgrade assistant.  This article specifies these:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022#macros
This is my result
1>Configuration: Debug
1>DevEnvDir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\
1>OutDir:
1>ProjectDir:
1>VisualStudioVersion: 17.0
1>AssemblySearchPaths: {CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory};{RawFileName}
1>AssemblyName: AcquisitionCoreTestApp
1>BaseIntermediateOutputPath: obj\
1>CscToolPath:

This is result from new .net 8 wpf application project I created, these show properly.  How come?  I compared the csproj file but didn't see anything obvious...
1>WpfApp1 -> C:\temp\net8prototypes\WpfApp1\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\WpfApp1.dll
1>Configuration: Debug
1>DevEnvDir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\
1>OutDir: bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\
1>ProjectDir: C:\temp\net8prototypes\WpfApp1\
1>VisualStudioVersion: 17.0
1>AssemblySearchPaths: {CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory};{RawFileName}
1>AssemblyName: WpfApp1
1>BaseIntermediateOutputPath: obj\
1>CscToolPath:


It may be related to the way MSBuild properties are initialized. At the beginning of the build process, the item's include attribute is evaluated. So, if you depend on files created during the build process, you must declare these as dynamic. Dynamic items are defined inside the target or using the CreateItem task.
Additionally, (ProjectDir) is only available after importing Microsoft.Common.Targets, while (MSBuildProjectDir) is a reserved property of MSBuild itself. Therefore, using the $(MSBuildXXX) properties will ensure that they are always available to you without having to import all the necessary references.

thanks for response, but like i said, there is very little difference in the csproj.. so doesn't really make sense.  

WinExe
net8.0-windows
enable
enable
true
True


I understand your confusion. Judging from the .csproj file you provided, there is indeed no obvious problem. Sometimes this issue can be due to a mismatch between the requested platform/configuration and how the project is actually defined. Something to note is the difference between the "Any CPU" preferred in the solution file (with spaces) and the "AnyCPU" actually used in the project file (without spaces). Also in SDK-based projects, true should be used instead of [path].
